# How do I set up my Routing for my MVC Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

Greetings New to MVC ... 
I am creating my first MVC Application, and I have created it as follows:

```
CustomUtilities/Controllers/GCItemRetrievalController.cs
CustomUtilities/Views/GCItemRetrieval/GCRetrieve.cshtml
CustomUtilities/Views/Web.config
```

I want to pull up "GCRetrieve.cshtml in my browser ... but I keep getting a 404 Error

```
http://mainsite/CustomUtilities/GCItemRetrieval/GCRetrieve
```

what am I doing wrong? I created the folders for the controllers, models, and Views in a seperate folder on the main system.

Comment: ...Do you have `GCRetrieve` action in `GCItemRetrievalController`? `CustomUtilities` is virtual directory in IIS?

Comment: Normally your url should have been like that http://mainsite/CustomUtilities/Controllers/GCItemRetrieval/GCRetrieve

Comment: I think I know what you mean, so ... I have two actions, one index(), and one SubmitForm, so, I need a GCRetrieve action? correct, I put the View ... GCRetrieve on the Index controller. Like I said I am new to this

Comment: Yess , @JasonEvans explained clearly down there , and there are tons of questions and answers out there  .

Comment: Have you added a Register Routes method yet? Your routes need to be registered in a route collection.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should look something like this:

```
public class GCItemRetrievalController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GCRetrieve()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When you navigate to the following url:

`http://mainsite/CustomUtilities/GCItemRetrieval/GCRetrieve`

It should find the controller's `GCRetrieve` method and execute it. The `return View()` call will look for a .`cshtml` file named `GCRetrieve.cshtml`, as that is the name of the method.

Comment: Here is my question, I created the folder CustomUtilities and inside I created /Models /Views, /Controllers/GCRetrieval, when I create an action/view in GCRetrieval, the view sits in /View outside of the folder /CustomUtilities not in /CustomUtilites/Views, Thus I moved the View and the Web.config into /CustomUtlities/Views ... Note, I tried to leave the View but it still doesn't work

Comment: I suggest you use the default `Views` folder, which was generated for you by ASP.NET MVC project template, rather then creating new custom folders. You do not need to create these customer folders, since the default `Views` folder structure will suffice. Is there a very good reason why you need to create a new folder e.g. `CustomUtilities\Views`?

Comment: I agree, can I still create the GCRetrieval controller inside of /CustomUtilites?

Comment: You can, but that means having to create your own view engine class, which inherits from `RazorViewEngine`, and then you can configure which paths the viewengine can scan for `cshtml` files. This isn't something I'm that familiar with to be honest. But Im sure there are plenty of examples you can Google for.

Comment: Something like this http://www.leonamarant.com/2011/02/17/adding-a-custom-directory-to-razor-view-engine-partial-view-locations-in-asp-net-mvc3/

Comment: Thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a MVC application a class file named as RouteConfig.cs is created in App_Start directory. It has default routing as

```
    public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In the above default routing:
if you want call a view CustomUtilities/Views/GCItemRetrieval/GCRetrieve.cshtml

I think CustomUtilities is your project name then use following

http://mainsite/GCItemRetrieval/GCRetrieve 
that is
[domanin]/[controllername]/[actionname]

For default routing detail you can refer to http://www.niceonecode.com/Q-A/DotNet/MVC/routing-in-mvc-4/20190